# Selenium WebDriver | Chrome | findElementByXPath |Java

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am currently running an automation test. On Firefox findElementByXPath works fine but on Chrome it is undefined. I was wondering if there was a another class I could use that would work on Chrome.

```
action.moveToElement(driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value='paypal']")).
    build().
    perform();
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@value='paypal']")).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: What error r u getting in chrome ?

Comment: Well its marked as red and the message is "The method findElementByXPath(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver" and in Problem " The method findElementByXPath(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver"

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(""))
```

Didn't say what language you're using, but here is the format I use in Java. Works in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing **click event** after moveToElement and findElementByXPath("//input[@value='paypal']") also you have written wrong syntax

```
action.moveToElement(driver.**findElementByXPath(**"//input[@value='paypal']"))**.click()**.build().perform();
```

You should try like this:

```
 Webelement ele =driver.findElement(By.XPath("//input[@value='paypal']"));  

action.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();

ele.click();
```